# Does primeness derive from a more generic concept?

Tags: abstract-algebra, prime-numbers

I am wondering whether there is a more generic understanding of the idea of primeness.

So far I am only aware of the prime elements of a commutative ring, from which - correct me if I'm wrong - prime numbers derive.

But can we extend the concept to higher layers of abstraction?

Comment: The two properties of being prime and being irreducible that can apply to elements in rings are both generalisations of the notion of an integer being prime. Not the other way around. The integers and the prime numbers came first, rings came afterwards, by a pretty decent margin.

Comment: This is pretty vague.  For any structure, it's natural to ask if there are "primitive" building blocks from which all examples can be constructed in some way.  Simple groups are sort of prime elements among finite groups, is that the sort of example you have in mind?  Of course, what "primitive" and "constructed" means is very dependent on context.

Comment: Also prime elements can be generalized to *prime ideals* in the context of ring theory.

Comment: In commutative algebra, prime ideal is then generalized to [primary ideal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primary_ideal), too. Primeness occurs frequently in mathematics, in different subjects. For example:"In mathematics, a prime geodesic on a hyperbolic surface is a primitive closed geodesic, i.e. a geodesic which is a closed curve that traces out its image exactly once. Such geodesics are called prime geodesics because, among other things, they obey an asymptotic distribution law similar to the prime number theorem. "

Comment: The most generic and basic concept for a prime is the definition of a prime number for a (positive) integer. This should give you the "generic understanding". All further "understanding" is based on this. You seem to assume that a more abstract encoding would give a new insight about "primeness". I think it is the wrong way around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - your intuition is correct.  Dedekind developed the notion of ideals, in the 19th century, building on Kummer's notion of ideal numbers (see comment by @Bill Dubuque).   In this context prime *elements* are essentially a particular case of the more satisfying notion of prime *ideal*.

Consider the integers adjoined with $\sqrt{-5}$.  We have $$\left(1+\sqrt{-5}\right)\left(1-\sqrt{-5}\right)=2\times 3.$$

However all of $1+\sqrt{-5}, 1-\sqrt{-5},2, 3$ are irreducible, so one cannot factorise the LHS and RHS further to a common factorisation of $6$.

This is somewhat unsatisfying.  At the time one issue was proving Fermat's last theorem for various exponents $p$.  One has the factorisation $$y^p=z^p-x^p$$
$$=(z-x)(z-\zeta x)\cdots(z-\zeta^{p-1}x),\qquad\qquad [1]
$$

where $\zeta=\exp{\frac{2\pi i}{p}}$.  Gabriel Lamé proposed using a standard descent argument, where you show that the above factors share few common prime factors, and are therefore almost $p$'th powers themselves (as their product is $y^p$).  Ultimately one shows that given one solution of Fermat's Last theorem with exponent $p$, one can find a smaller one, yielding a contradiction as this process cannot continue forever.

However this relies on there being a unique factorisation of numbers into primes, which is no longer true for the above factors, as they live in $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta]$.

For example if $p=23$, then we have $\frac{1+\sqrt{-23}}2, \frac{1-\sqrt{-23}}2\in \mathbb{Z}[\zeta]$.  Again:

$$
\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{-23}}2\right) \left(\frac{1-\sqrt{-23}}2\right)=6=2\times 3.
$$

Returning to the first example if you consider instead the principal ideals $\left(1+\sqrt{-5}\right), \left(1-\sqrt{-5}\right),(2), (3)$, then one can factorise them further into prime ideals.

\begin{align}
(2)&=& A^2,
\\
(3)&=& BC,
\\
\left(1+\sqrt{-5}\right)&=&AB,
\\
\left(1-\sqrt{-5}\right)&=&AC,
\end{align}

where \begin{align}A&=&\left(1+\sqrt{-5},1-\sqrt{-5}\right),\\
B&=&\left(1+\sqrt{-5},3\right),\\
C&=&\left(1-\sqrt{-5},3\right).\end{align}

Here $A,B,C$ are prime ideals.  Even though they are not actual numbers in the ring, in spirit they are there, and by taking them into account everything works much better.

In general all ideals in cyclotomic rings (and more generally Dedekind rings) factorise uniquely into prime ideals, even if elements do not factorise uniquely into prime elements.  Using this, Kummer was able to prove Fermat's Last Theorem for a large class of exponents $p$ - namely regular primes $p$, where the size of the ideal class group of $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta]$ (intuitively the multiplicative group generated by prime ideals, modulo prime elements) is not divisible by $p$.  This condition means that if $$(z-\zeta^r x)=A^p$$ for some ideal $A$, then $A=(a)$, so $z-\zeta^r x=ua^p$ for some element $a$ and unit $u$. All we are saying here is that if $p$ does not divide the size of a group, and $A^p$ is the identity in that group, then $A$ is also the identity.

Clearly this property of $p$ is useful in using $[1]$ to produce a descent argument.  For more mathematical and historical details see [this article](https://www.math.toronto.edu/%7Eila/Kummer.pdf).

However that is just one reason why the notion of prime ideal is the natural abstraction of the notion of prime element, and more fundamental.

In classical geometry, points were taken as primitive notions and geometry was built from that starting point.  However in algebraic geometry, we take rings of functions as our primitive object (or more generally schemes) and the notion of point is replaced with prime ideal. That is if you have some functions on a space, and you look at the ideal of functions that vanish at a point, then if $fg$ belongs to the ideal, then clearly either $f$ or $g$ does.

Turning it around, given any ring, you can pretend that it is the ring of functions on some space, and the [prime ideals of the ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrum_of_a_ring) are the points of the space.

In logic and combinatorics [ultrafilters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultrafilter#Ultrafilter_on_the_power_set_of_a_set) are a key concept.  Given a set $X$, the elements of $x$ correspond to the prime elements of the Boolean algebra $P(X)$.  However the ultrafilters are the prime ideals of that algebra.  See [here](https://chalkdustmagazine.com/features/pretend-numbers/) for how this case of the abstraction from prime element to prime ideal arises naturally in children's guessing games.

Comment: Kummer had no notion of (ring) ideals - that was due to Dedekind. Rather, Kummer's "ideal numbers" are forerunner's of modern valuation theoretic methods, e.g. see Lemmermeyer's [Jacobi and Kummer's Ideal Numbers](https://arxiv.org/abs/1108.6066). Your claims about $A,B,C$ being (Kummer) "ideal numbers" are incorrect.  Many popular expositions on the history of number theory are greatly inaccurate - esp. on these and related topics.

Comment: @BillDubuque Thank you very much for the clarification.

Comment: Thank you very much this is very interesting!